# SSLSocket with hardware token key

Tags: java, smartcard

I'm interested in using a client token to perform client certificate authentication for SSL/TLS, but the client private key resides on a (non-PKCS11-accessible) hardware token.  I originally wanted to replace the key manager, but I can't return the private keys from the token, so I am considering modifying the underlying SSLSocket and related classes to accomplish my goal.

In which Java classes is the private key used in the establishment of the TLS session so that I could override that functionality?  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing this by creating a new provider.  My provider registers the following:

- Hardware device abstraction that implements PrivateKey; I called it "Token".
- Custom keystore that extends KeyStoreSpi.  The keystore knows how to enumerate certificates and aliases from the Token.
- Custom Signature object that knows how to perform signing operations using Token.  I only needed to implement a subset of the RSA/SHA signature algorithms for my class.
- Custom socket factory that extends SSLSocketFactory.  I did this to set the preferred cipher suite.

The provider registers my Token as a PKCS11 device to avoid default password prompts during client authentication (I use custom password prompts for the token PIN).  I put my provder at the top of the providers list, created a new SSLContext and set the SSLSocketFactory, and finally established the connection.

-Djavax.net.debug=true on the client and server was my friend throughout.